# Reactjs pass props based on loaded component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need advice on how to pass a Reactjs prop from a component to my app when it's loaded. I'm able to pass the value when my props are in app.js but how do I handle the prop when loading from a separate component?

Here's what's working so far in app.js:

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import { Grid, Nav, Navbar, NavItem, Jumbotron } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { LinkContainer, IndexLinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';

function HeaderTitle(props) {
  return <h1>{props.name}</h1>;
}

const headerTitle = <HeaderTitle name="About Page" />;

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() { ...

<p>{headerTitle.props.name}</p>
```

Comment: Do you mean pass props from App to HeaderTitle?

Comment: I'm looking to pass the prop from each component as it is loaded using react-router.

Comment: Ok, so child to parent? Please see my answer below - part 2

Comment: But pass the props where?

Comment: I'm want to pass the title props from the components in /views to the div in the parent app.js.

Comment: Gotcha, then my answer below (child to parent) covers exactly that

Comment: I'll try what you suggested and report back. Thanks.

Comment: if want to pass props to all children deep down the root use react "context".

Answer (score 1):

**Parent to Child**

If you want to pass all the props through:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <HeaderTitle {...this.props} />     
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or if just some:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <HeaderTitle name={this.props.name} />     
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Child to Parent**

If you mean the other way round, you need to use a callback

```
// app
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <HeaderTitle onGetName={(name) => this.setState({childName: name})} />     
      <p>{this.state.childName}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

// headertitle
componentDidMount() {
  // maybe some async call or something
  axios
    .get('/api/say-my-name')
    .then(response => this.props.onGetName(response.data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I guess you need some thing like importing components from one file to another. So you have options to import and export components from another file since React components are basically Objects. In index.js if you have something like

```
const headerTitle = <HeaderTitle name="About Page" />;

export default headerTitle;
```

and in app.js

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import { Grid, Nav, Navbar, NavItem, Jumbotron } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { LinkContainer, IndexLinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import HeaderTitle from '/// put the file relative location to app.js"

function HeaderTitle(props) {
  return <h1>{props.name}</h1>;
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() { ...

<p>{headerTitle.props.name}</p>
}
```